# Going back out of a while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

So I have written this code in my `MainMenu` class and it worked fine:

```
public void Start() //Start method
{
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)  
    {
        ShowMeny();
        SwitchMethod();

        NumChoice = InputHelper.ReadIntegerConsole();
        if (NumChoice == 0) // if the input is 0, set done to true and stop the loop
            done = true;

// ...
```

However, here I wrote it in another class, and when you press 0, it is supposed to go back to my `MainMenu`. Why can't I use the same kind of code? All this does is looping the `ShowMenu`.

```
private void CalcMenu()
{
    bool Done = false;

    while (!Done)
    {
        ShowMenu();
        if (MenuChoice == 0)
            Done = true;
    }
}
```

If you press 0 here, it repeats 2 times then exits. Here is the whole class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class WorkingSchedule
{
    int MenuChoice = -1;

    public void Start()
    {
        ShowMenu();
        CalcMenu();
        //LoopOneWeeks();
        //LoopTwoNights
        //ShowResults();

    }

    private void ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Välj det schema som du vill se:");
        Console.WriteLine("_______________________________");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Visa en lista de veckor du ska jobba");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Visa en lista de nätter du ska jobba");
        Console.WriteLine("0. För att återvända till huvudmenyn");
        MenuChoice = InputHelper.ReadIntegerConsole();
        Console.WriteLine("Ditt val: " + MenuChoice);
    }

    private void CalcMenu()
    {
        bool Done = false;

        while (!Done)
        {
            ShowMenu();
            if (MenuChoice == 0)
            {
                Done = true;
                ReturnMainMenu();
            }
            else if (MenuChoice == 1)
            {

            }
            else if (MenuChoice == 2)
            {

            }
        } 
    }

    private void ReturnMainMenu()
    {
        MenuProgram MPObj = new MenuProgram();
        MPObj.Start();
    }
```

*InputHelper.ReadIntegerConsole is a input helper class*

Comment: Where is `MenuChoice` declared, and where is it assigned?

Comment: @MichaelDunlap Its an instance variable.

Comment: And does the `ShowMenu()` call include the code that assigns to `MenuChoice`?

Comment: Well yes, MenuChoice is assigned a userinput which is inside the ShowMenu method.

Comment: So is MenuChoice scoped to the `ShowMenu()` method? Or does it exist as a property of the `CalcMenu` class?

Comment: It is scoped to ShowMenu.

Comment: Can you please share more code about where and how MenuChoice is created and assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually exiting your loop when you have your `MenuChoice == 0` branch.

```
private void CalcMenu()
{
    bool Done = false;

    while (!Done)
    {
        ShowMenu();
        if (MenuChoice == 0)
        {
            Done = true;
            //ReturnMainMenu();
        }
        else if (MenuChoice == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (MenuChoice == 2)
        {

        }
    }
    ReturnMainMenu(); //This should only happen when you exit the loop.
}
```

Edit:

Looks like you are showing the menu in Start() before you show the menu again in CalcMenu.

```
public void Start()
{
    //ShowMenu();
    CalcMenu();
    //LoopOneWeeks();
    //LoopTwoNights
    //ShowResults();

}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that and corrected it, now it does exit but the menu is repeated 2 times.

Comment: Please see my new answer given your move complete question.

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me the same result. If I enter 0, then the Menu is repeated, if I press 0  again, I do get return to my MainMenu. Why is this menu repeated two times?

Comment: In `Start`, why are you calling `ShowMenu` before `CalcMenu`?

Comment: *Facepalm Dammit such a silly mistake. Sorry for wasting you time. Feeling really stupid now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the loop otherwise it will end as infinite loop. Because `Done` will never become true.

```
while (!Done)
{
  ShowMenu();           
  if (MenuChoice == 0)
  {
    Done = true;
  }   
}
```

Your first method works because you are changing the value of `Done` variable inside the `while` loop which breaks the loop. But in the second method you are not changing the value of `Done`. Its always false; so the condition `!Done` is always true and loop become infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above answers are correct. In order to exit your while loop you need to have the exit logic inside of the loop itself. As an alternative to the proposed solutions you can also try.

```
while( MenuChoice != 0 )
{
    ShowMenu();
}
```